# How to display SUM fields from a detailed table in a master table

Tags: sql, database, firebird

What is the best approach to display the summery of DETAILED.Fields in its master table?

E.g. I have a master table called 'BILL' with all the bill related data and a detailed table ('BILL_DETAIL') with the bill detailed related data, like NAME, PRICE, TAX, ... Now I want to list all BILLS, **without the details**, but with the **sum** of the PRICE and TAX stored in the detail table.

Here is a simplified schema of that tables:

```
TABLE BILL
----------
- ID
- NAME
- ADDRESS
- ...

TABLE BILL_DETAIL
-----------------
- ID
- BILLID
- PORDUCT_NAME
- PRICE
- TAX
- ...
```

The retrieved table row should look like this:

```
BILL.CUSTOMER_NAME, BILL.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS, sum(BILL_DETAIL.PRICE), sum(BILL.DETAIL.TAX), ...
```

Any sugguestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `GROUP BY` and a `LEFT JOIN` should get you what you want:

```
Select
  bill.customer_name,
  bill.customer_address,
  Sum(bill_detail.price),
  Sum(bill_detail.tax)
From bill
Left Join bill_detail On ( bill_detail.billid = bill.id )
Group By bill.id, bill.customer_name, bill.customer_address
```

Make sure to group by all columns of table `bill` that you have in the column list of your select.

Comment: The problem is, that my BILL table has a lot fields, and it has also some more detailed tables, with other fields I want to sum up. I aleady use some other joins, too. It's actually a big SELECT query. Not sure how fast GROUP BY is. I also thought using VIEWS to sum up all my detailed tables and then join it?

Comment: I would not expect you to have any performance problems caused by the `GROUP BY`, but you will have to try for yourself. The view could improve readability, but again, you will have to try how it performs with your model.

Comment: write it out.  views are almost always not a benefit